# How to read paragraphs from a file while avoiding the blank space between them into an array?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure this out. I'm very new to C++. I have tried using this: (what modifications would be needed?)

```
while(!openFile.fail())
{  
getline(openFile,myArray[size])
}
```

My array size is the same as the number of paragraphs. However, I can't figure out how to consider the paragraphs as one element of the array.

Edit [How I did it]:

```
    while(!openFile.fail()) // while no errors keep going.
    {  
      // then i needed a for loop to iterate [size of array] times.
     for ( int i = 0; i < sizzArr; i++)    
       {
         getline(tempFile, copyDataF); // this getline gets my first line from the data file into our copyDataF.  
         while (copyDataF.length() != 0) // when what we copied is not empty 
         {
          arr[i] = arr[i] + copyDataF + "\n";
          getline(tempFile, copyDataF); /* assuming next line is blank, our while loop will stop,
 the iteration will repeat till end of file (+ depends on the for loop). */ 
         }
 

    }
```

[ thank you everyone who tried to help as i admit my question wasn't clear enough ]

Comment: Can you show the file and the expected output.

Comment: What problems do you have with this code? Please also show a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what step you're having trouble with, but if I understand correctly. You have a file of some kind that you want to read from and a `std::string` array initialized to have size equaling the number of lines in the file. You can easily open a file with [`<ifstream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) using [`open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) and then read the file line by line with [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), adding each line to the resultant array.

If you want to perform any further logic (searching for spaces in a line, whatever else) this should be enough to get you headed in the right direction. For context, the `./foo.txt` file contains 3 newline separated strings of text.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ifstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    file.open("./foo.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    string lines[3];
    int i = 0;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        // begin reading the file line by line
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            cout << "line: " << line << endl;
            lines[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "error opening file" << endl;
    }

    cout << "printing array" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << lines[j] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```